# Discourse replies to an answer : how to get nested comments?

Tags: discourse

By default, discourses answers and replies to answers are organized chronologically

- [QUESTION]
- Answer #1 (Monday)
- Answer #2 (Tuesday, early)
- 1st reply to answer #2 (Tuesday, late)
- 2nd reply to answer #2 (Wednesday, early)
- 1st reply to answer #1 (Wednesday, late)
- 2nd reply to answer #1 (Friday)
- 3nd reply to answer #2 (Saturday)

We know that Discourse does records the child-relation of replies to a parent answer, because as admin we can select an answer and its children :

[image]

I now want that each reply to an answer appears on my discourse, as for Stackoverflow/Stackexchange's "comment vs answer", below the answer it comments. Such as :

- [QUESTION]
- Answer #1 (Monday)

  - 1st reply to answer #1 (Wednesday)
  - 2nd reply to answer #1 (Friday)
- Answer #2 (Tuesday)

  - 1st reply to answer #2 (Tuesday)
  - 2nd reply to answer #2 (Wednesday)
  - 3nd reply to answer #2 (Saturday)

**Q: Is there a plugins or solution to have discrete, nested comments as for stack-exchanges sites ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [How to get nested comments? (stackoverflow-like & tiny)](https://meta.discourse.org/t/how-to-get-nested-comments-stackoverflow-like-tiny/56660)